# Access file inside folder, matlab mac

Tags: macos, matlab

I have about 300 **files** I would like to access and import in Matlab, all these files are inside  300 **folders**.

The first **file** lie in the directory users/matt/Documents/folder_1 with the filename **line.csv** the 2nd file lie in users/matt/Documents/folder_2 with filename **line.csv**

So I would like to import the data from the 300 line.csv files in Matlab so I can take the average value. Is this possible? I am using mac osx btw.

I know what do with the .csv file, but I have no clue how to access them efficiently.

Comment: Read them in a loop. That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: All we are doing is generating the string for every file path using [`sprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and the loop index `i`, and then reading the csv file using [`csvread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) and storing the data in a [`cell` array](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).

```
for i = 1:300 % Loop 300 times.

    % Full path pointing to the csv file.
    file_path = sprintf('users/matt/Documents/folder_%d/line.csv', i);

    % Read data from csv and store it in a cell array.
    data{i} = csvread(file_path);
end

% Do your computations here.
% ...
```

Remember to replace the `300` by the actual number of folders that you have.